# SAML Assertion Value XML Signature Wrapping

Tags: .net, xml, saml, word-wrap, assertion

Using .NET 3.5

I have been asked by a client of mine to improve the way I check a SAML response that they send to me.

They send through a response that is digitally signed with a shared certificate.  That all validates fine, but they are picking me up on the fact that using tools such as Burp, they are able to intercept the response they send me and alter the ID value that is being sent.  This is known as XML Signature Wrapping .

My question is how do I check that the value I receive has not been altered ?

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Is the assertion signed, or is the response signed? How are you validating it today?

Answer (score 0):

When you validate an XML signature in .NET against a pre-shared certificate you should do two things:

1. Call `SignedXml.CheckSignature()` to check that the content the signature refers to is valid according to the signature.
2. Check the References of the signature (in the SAML2 case there should be only one) and then call `SignedXml.GetIdElement()` with the id of the reference. Then use *the returned node* in further processing. That will make sure that the node that you are processing is *the same* node that SignedXml validated.

For further reading see my blog post at https://coding.abel.nu/2015/12/xml-signatures-and-references/